# 5th degree equation roots relation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quintics

Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be the roots of $x^5+x^4+2x^3+4x^2+7x+1=0$ the question is:find the value of  $$\frac{1}{2-a}+\frac{1}{2-b}+\frac{1}{2-c}+\frac{1}{2-d}+\frac{1}{2-e}$$  my try is in below
with respect to $2-a,2-b,...$ we can use $$(x+2)^5+(x+2)^4+2(x+2)^3+4(x+2)^2+7(x+2)+1=0$$ so we can find $$\frac{1}{a'}+\frac{1}{b'}+\frac 1{c'}+\frac{1}{d'}+\frac1{d'}$$
and it is standard for roots relation (I remember from the past)
$$x^5+\cdots+32+16+16+16+14+1=0\\(x-a')(x-b')(x-c')(x-d')(x-e')=0\\a'b'c'd'e'=-95$$and $$a'b'c'd'+a'b'c'e'+...=?\\x^180+x^132+x^116+x^124+7x=159x$$ so $$\frac{1}{a'}+\frac{1}{b'}+\frac 1{c'}+\frac{1}{d'}+\frac1{d'}=\frac{159}{95}$$
Am I right?

Is there a different technic to find the value?

Comment: I don't understand why you have used $x+2$; I would use $2-x$ isntead. Other than that, I would do it the same way as you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: thank you for your attention, the first equation roots $x=a$ so $x+2=a' \to a=a'-2\\(x-a')=(x+2-a)$  , honestly I am in doubt this point of solution

Comment: $x=2-a$ iff $a=2-x$, so $2-a,2-b,\cdots, 2-e$ are the roots of $(2-x)^5+(2-x)^4+2(2-x)^3+4(2-x)^2+7(2-x)+1=0$.

Comment: @mathlove: I think you are correct and I was in the wrong way.